# 6 check boxes when any two are selected the rest should disable

Tags: javascript

With the code below, one out of the six possibilities for 3 of the boxes only 3 work as expected. Even though there are 6 if/else statement and 3 listeners to cover any order that the check boxes are checked.

I was trying to get the first 3 to work. When only doing the first two boxes they work fine but with three now three of six possible combinations work. Will need to get to all 6 working in any order their pressed the key is that if two boxes are checked the rest disable than when you deselect one they all re-enable.

Note the program itself works fine and the radio buttons are grouped so only one can be selected at a time.

```
        inches.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            Object source = e.getItemSelectable();

            if (source == inches) {
                if (inches.isSelected() && feet.isSelected()) {
                    miles.setEnabled(false);
                    centi.setEnabled(false);
                    meters.setEnabled(false);
                    km.setEnabled(false);}

            else{
                    miles.setEnabled(true);
                    centi.setEnabled(true);
                    meters.setEnabled(true);
                    km.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if (inches.isSelected() && miles.isSelected()) {
                feet.setEnabled(false);
                centi.setEnabled(false);
                meters.setEnabled(false);
                km.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else{
                feet.setEnabled(true);
                centi.setEnabled(true);
                meters.setEnabled(true);
                km.setEnabled(true);
        }
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED);
            }
        }
            });
    feet.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            Object source = e.getItemSelectable();{


                if (source == feet) {
            if (feet.isSelected() && miles.isSelected()) {
                inches.setEnabled(false);
                centi.setEnabled(false);
                meters.setEnabled(false);
                km.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else{
                inches.setEnabled(true);
                centi.setEnabled(true);
                meters.setEnabled(true);
                km.setEnabled(true);
        }
            if (feet.isSelected() && inches.isSelected()) {
                miles.setEnabled(false);
                centi.setEnabled(false);
                meters.setEnabled(false);
                km.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else{
                miles.setEnabled(true);
                centi.setEnabled(true);
                meters.setEnabled(true);
                km.setEnabled(true);
        }
                  if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED);}
            }
        }
            });
    miles.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            Object source = e.getItemSelectable();

           if(source == miles) {
               if (inches.isSelected() && miles.isSelected()) {
                   centi.setEnabled(false); 
                   feet.setEnabled(false);
                    meters.setEnabled(false);
                    km.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else{
                    feet.setEnabled(true);
                    centi.setEnabled(true);
                    meters.setEnabled(true);
                    km.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if (feet.isSelected() && miles.isSelected()) {
                inches.setEnabled(false);
                centi.setEnabled(false);
                meters.setEnabled(false);
                km.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else{
                inches.setEnabled(true);
                centi.setEnabled(true);
                meters.setEnabled(true);
                km.setEnabled(true);
        }
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED);
            }
        }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the selected checkboxes in an array and update it, unchecking as updated

```js
var currentSelected = [undefined, undefined];
for (i in (l = ["inches", "miles", "centi", "feet", "meters", "km"]))
  document.getElementById(l[i]).addEventListener("change", onChange);

function onChange() {
  if (this.checked) {
    currentSelected.unshift(this);
    (currentSelected.pop() || {}).checked = false;
  } else {
    currentSelected.push(undefined);
    currentSelected.splice(currentSelected.indexOf(this), 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input id="inches" type="checkbox"> Inches
  <br><input id="miles" type="checkbox"> Miles
  <br><input id="centi" type="checkbox"> Centimeters
  <br><input id="feet" type="checkbox"> Feet
  <br><input id="meters" type="checkbox"> Meters
  <br><input id="km" type="checkbox"> Kilometers
</body>
```

This doesn't directly answer your question, however it allows user to change selections while only keeping a max of 2 options selected. As a direct answer, the following should work:

```js
var currentSelected = [undefined, undefined];
var names = ["inches", "miles", "centi", "feet", "meters", "km"];
for (i in names) {
  names[i] = document.getElementById(names[i]);
  names[i].addEventListener("change", onChange);
}

function onChange() {
  var nChecked = 0;

  for (i in names)
    if (names[i].checked)
      nChecked++;
  if (nChecked >= 2)
    for (i in names) {
      if (!names[i].checked)
        names[i].disabled = true;
    }
  else
    for (i in names)
      names[i].disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input id="inches" type="checkbox"> Inches
  <br><input id="miles" type="checkbox"> Miles
  <br><input id="centi" type="checkbox"> Centimeters
  <br><input id="feet" type="checkbox"> Feet
  <br><input id="meters" type="checkbox"> Meters
  <br><input id="km" type="checkbox"> Kilometers
</body>
```